# How to incline the plane of a camera view?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, perspectivecamera

I have a background that is a GUITexture, and some 3d objects between the background and the camera.

```
 __         \
|  |         \ ___
|bg| Object   |Cam| 
|__|         /
            /
```

Current Result:

```
 ________
|   bg   |
|        |
| Object |
|        |
|________|
```

Desired Result:

```
     ______
    /  bg  \
   /        \
  /  Object  \
 /____________\
```

How can I get everything that is going to display on the screen, rotate it so that it is inclined to certain angle and display it on the screen so that it appears to be distorted?

Comment: So if would grab picture of current results view, draw that picture on a plane, and rotate the plane, would that work? (basically would look like perspective rotation in photoshop)

Comment: @mgear That's exactly what I'm looking for, performance is my only concern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally settled with having the two cameras render to a target texture, and created a third camera looking at a rotated plane with the render texture.